# Angularjs "jump to page" pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pagination function, and I would like to create a textbox and button where user can enter the page number they want to go. Is there a way to do this? Would appreciate it if I could get a reference link or something. Thanks!

My HTML :

```
<div class="pagingDiv">
<button class="btnPaging" ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
    Previous
</button>
{{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
<button class="btnPaging" ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
    Next
</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
                 $scope.currentPage = 0;
                 $scope.pageSize = 4;
                 $scope.data = [];
                 $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
                     return Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize);
                 }
                 for (var i=0; i < $scope.displayPage.length; i++) {
                     $scope.data.push("Item "+ i);
                 }
```

How it look like currently

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: add `ng-model="currentPage` to your textbox?  or have a function that sets the value of `currentPage` to the model bound to the textbox?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a text box and bind the model `currentPage` to it.

```
    <button class="btnPaging" ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
Next
    </button>
    <input ng-model="currentPage" type="text">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ChangePage()"></button>
```

You can use the ChangePage function on you angular file to change the page. and use the text box to bind the current page variable.